# How can I fix the problem of an extra output line after I input my 3rd letter? I can't use while loops or range in the program

Tags: python

When I run the code, the 3rd guess gives me an output of High/Low.  On the 3rd try, I don't need it to tell me if I'm high or low. How can I fix the problem with out using "while" loops or "range."  We haven't covered these two keywords yet.

## python

```
print("You have 3 tries to guess the letter.")
letter = "F"
tries = 0

# [ ] create letter_guess() function, call the function to test
def letter_guess(tries):
    if not tries == 3:
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
        tries = tries + 1
        check = check_guess (guess,letter)

        if check == True:
            print('Winner')       

        else:
           letter_guess(tries)

    else:
        print ("GAME OVER!")
        pass

# def check_guess(guess,letter)        
def check_guess (guess, letter):

#if else to see if correct letter
    if letter == guess.upper():
        print ("correct")
        return True

    elif letter < guess.upper():
        print ("You are wrong, guess lower.")
        return False

    elif letter > guess.upper():
        print ("You are wrong, guess higher.")
        return False

    else:
        print("Invalid response!")
        return False




letter_guess(tries)
```

Comment: To clarify, you cannot use a for loop or a while loop?

Comment: correct, in the next unit we will cover while loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get result similar to a loop is to use recursion. But if you have not done loops yet, you almost certainly have not done recursion. So just use straightforward code.

The tricky part is that you need to ask for a guess, input the guess, and check for a correct guess *three times*, once for each guess. However, you need to give feedback on whether the guess is high or low only *two times*. Therefore, you cannot put those actions in the same function. Just split them into separate functions, and handle each guess in your main routine. No need to count guesses--the position in the main routine makes that clear.

```
"""Guess-a-letter game."""


def get_guess(letter):
    """Get a guess an note if it is correct. If correct, return None.
    Otherwise, return the guess."""
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").upper()
    if guess == letter:
        print("Correct: You win!")
        return None
    else:
        return guess


def give_feedback(guess, letter):
    """Give feedback on a wrong guess."""
    if letter < guess:
        print("You are wrong, guess lower.")
    else:
        print("You are wrong, guess higher.")


def letter_guess():
    # Store the letter for the user to guess.
    letter = "F"

    # Introduce the game.
    print("You have 3 tries to guess the letter.")

    # Handle the first guess.
    guess = get_guess(letter)
    if guess is None:
        return  # Success!
    give_feedback(guess, letter)

    # Handle the second guess.
    guess = get_guess(letter)
    if guess is None:
        return  # Success!
    give_feedback(guess, letter)

    # Handle the third and last guess.
    guess = get_guess(letter)
    if guess is None:
        return  # Success!
    print("You were wrong three times. GAME OVER!")


letter_guess()
```

Comment: Thank you.  Trying to grasp the call back on the def keyword.  After running it a couple of times on Visualize Python, I think I have a better understanding of call back to def.

Comment: When you Return None, what does that actually do in the code?

Comment: `None` is a code to the calling routine `letter_guess` that the user's guess was correct. Then `letter_guess` returns to the call at the bottom of the program, which ends the program. If the guess was wrong, the guess itself, which cannot be `None`, is returned. I needed some way to tell the difference between a correct guess and a wrong one, and that is the way I chose. There are other ways--I did not know what you have learned so far so I chose this easy-to-understand way. Another way was to return a 2-tuple: the guess and a code for right/wrong guess.